# Pythonw gui does not run - how to debug

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am new to python and trying to figure out a problem that gui doesn't launch when clicking on the .pyw file.

On my windows 10 machine, I have installed python 3.5, and environment path is set.

I was given a set of python files (.py) and some looks like shortcut file (.pyw). And I was told to double click the file then a gui will launch.

Some .pyw works well, gui launch.

However there are some failed. After double click, there was a quick cmd terminal open and closed automatically. Then no gui pop out.

I want to know what is the cause and how do I debug it.

From the properties of .pyw file, is is pointing to one of the .py file.

Let me know if posting the .py file helps. I will then post here.

Comment: Probably there are error messages in the console, but the window gets dismissed so quickly, you cannot see what they are. Open your own command prompt and cd to the directory with the .pyw files. Then type the file name and see what error messages you get.

Comment: Pyw -3.5 testprog got no error at cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve it by selecting the correct pylauncher to open the file.